# Aggregating logs in AWS CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a web request log with the following structure:

```
[ts, app, controller, action, method, url, elapsed]
```

I would like to see requests that are taking `elapsed > 1000` grouped by `app`, `controller` and `action`, is this even possible with AWS CloudWatch?

Comment: Yes this is possible. You'll need to read the documentation to work out how to do it. These two pages will help http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/ExtractBytesExample.html and https://www.opsgenie.com/blog/2014/08/how-to-use-cloudwatch-to-generate-alerts-from-logs

Comment: Hi.  I read that already and I am afraid they do not explain what I am asking. I am talking about doing a "group by" and show aggregated metrics, not about sending alarms.

Comment: I suspect you can alert when it happens, and maybe you can even create a graph, but I don't think you can group as you're wanting. I think you'll need to look at more fully featured systems for that.

Comment: That is what I was afraid. I am happy with LogEntries.com, but just wondering if I could do the same with CloudWatch.